# I want to automate k8s dummy node creation using ansible, how to do this dynamically?

Tags: dictionary, kubernetes, ansible, big-ip

I want to create 3 dummy nodes in k8s node1, node2 and node3. To create these nodes I should give the below values:

- name: `node_name`
- mac_address: `mac_address`
- public_ip: `public_ip`
- pod_cidr: `pod_cidr`

I have to create a condition that I should take `node_name` as key, based on node name k8s template has to choose the above values. How can I do this without using ansible k8s module?

I can do this for 1 node giving kubectl command in tasks and k8s template file in templates, but I want the template should be common for all the 3 nodes and it has to choose the values based on name.

template file:

````
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Node
  metadata:
    name: node1
    annotations:
      # Provide the MAC address of the BIG-IP VXLAN tunnel
      flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: '{"VtepMAC":"{{ mac_address }}"}'
      flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: "vxlan"
      flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: "true"
      # Provide the IP address you assigned as the BIG-IP VTEP
      flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: "{{ public_ip }}"
  spec:
    # Define the flannel subnet you want to assign to the BIG-IP device.
    # Be sure this subnet does not collide with any other Nodes' subnets.
    podCIDR: "{{ pod_cidr }}"```
````

tasks file:

```
---
- name: "Create node1 dummy node"
  command: kubectl apply --kubeconfig={{ kubeadmin_config }} -f templates/node1_dummy_node.yaml
  delegate_to: "{{groups['k8s-master-primary'][0]}}"
  run_once: true
```

Please help me create proper condition for this.

Comment: Do you have the requisite to do it manually, or can you use something like KubeSpray? (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubespray/)

Comment: I already have a k8s cluster created manually, I want to create dummy nodes now, so that I can create a route between k8s and other nodes( like bigip, other k8s node....etc)